# OpenGL texture mapping; Trying to map a texture to triangles as defined in .obj file

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm rather new with OpenGL (actually not so much new as inexperienced) and one of the first things I'm trying to do is to write a code that takes a .obj file (right now I'm using [this one](https://www.yobi3d.com/#!/search?q=3d%2520file%2520stormtrooper)) and displays it. [This](http://shrani.si/f/1b/ga/2z9ZOK7w/strooper.png) is what I'm getting (you can see the head-piece part being mapped to the torso, for instance, but it's intact, so I'm thinking this isn't entirely wrong).

(I had no problems drawing the polygons so I'll just skip to textures.) With the .obj file I downloaded, I got some .tga files, a .dae file and a .mtl file. I figured (please correct me if I'm wrong) that since the mapping is described in the .obj file itself, all I really need is the correct .tga (Stormtrooper_D, in this particular case).

As far as .tga loading goes, I followed a tutorial on NeHe Productions to a point, so I don't think that's the source of my problem. What I'm doing is:

- "f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9" this is one triangle. 1, 4 and 7 are the vertex indexes. 2, 5 and 8 are texture indexes.
- I save the textures and vertices in their respective vectors and the indexes that I get from the face lines in theirs.
- After I load the .tga, I use the following sequence to bind it:

  glGenTextures(1, &text.texID);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, text.texID);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, text.width, text.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text.imageData);
- I draw them with glTexCoord2f, followed by glVertex3f for each vertex of a triangle. I call glEnable before doing so and glDisable when I'm done.

So my (first?) question is obviously; from the procedure I described, is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong? One thing I'm not entirely sure about is wether I'm using the correct files. Or enough of them, even. I'm using just one of the three .tgas and no .dae and .mlt.

If there's any additional information I didn't (but should) disclose, please tell me and I'll add it.

Comment: I would expect you to get to the textures via the .mtl (material) file.  Have a look at http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/  and  http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/

Comment: I forgot to mention the .mtl file which was also included, yes. It specifies which .tgas to use and properties such as lighting, if I'm not mistaken. At this point I hardcoded .tga and disregarded lighting and similar properties because if I understand correctly, the mapping itself has nothing to do with them (?).

Comment: I don't know if this is standard (OBJ is a vendor format, so it's not really standardized or clearly defined), but I found that the texture coordinates in at least some OBJ files are y-inverted. Try replacing all second texture coordinates `t` by `1 - t`.

Comment: It could also be that your TGA loader is loading the image flipped on the Y axis from what OpenGL is expecting. Try flipping the texture upside down and that may fix the issue as well.

Comment: Reto Koradi, that did it! Thank you very much!